# How to identify duplicate code in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I do code merge between branches sometimes the auto merge in Visual Studio 2022 may result in duplicated code segments or duplicated methods. So in such a scenario, I need to efficiently find and remove the duplicated code segments.

How can I find duplicated lines or duplicated code segments in Visual Studio 2022? Is there a method for it or are there any plugins available to download?

I am aware the for Visual Studio Code there's a plug-in by the name duplicate-lines-finder (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tlevesque2.duplicate-finder) but what I need is for Visual Studio 2022

Comment: In the 'Analyze' menu  you have the 'Analyze Solution For Code Clones' option. (Tool must be  enabled in installer under 'individual components' - 'Code Tools' - 'Code Clone', may only be available in the Enterprise Edition).

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio Enterprise, first install

Visual Studio Installer=>Individual Components => Code Tools => Code Clone

[image]

Then use Visual Studio Enterprise Edition to open your project and click

Analyze=> Analyze Solution For Code Clones to find duplicate code blocks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### CodeRush

If you use **Visual Studio Community Edition**, you can install **CodeRush** extension, from DevExpress (https://www.devexpress.com/products/coderush)

It's free (https://www.devexpress.com/coderush-free) and quite powerful.

See the documentation for Duplicate Code analysis:
https://docs.devexpress.com/CodeRushForRoslyn/401720/static-code-analysis/duplicate-code